# Facebook graph api $fb->api('/me') doesn't return anything

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app working great until today, and I noticed that `$fb->api('/me')`  doesn't return anything, while `$fb->getUser()`  still returns the `UID`.

I did not change anything, and the $fb object is a simple one :

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $app_id,
      'secret' => $app_secret,
    ));
```

Maybe a Facebook temporary problem ?
thanks !

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: All the code under the line does not work. (i think the server doesn't show php errors)

Comment: Well enable them. You can't possibly debug your code if you can' see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I know, but i don't have access to the server to do the change :(

Comment: maybe you´re using an old version of the php sdk? if yes, upgrade to the newest one, and check the example code again.

Comment: You can enable them in your code with Error_Reporting()

Comment: I succeded in showing an error and i have : Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed thrown in F:\Ftp\Yannick\ideesrecues\src\base_facebook.php on line 967

So i think it's a SSL problem...  (very annoying). Thanks anyway !

Comment: It's a FB bug for today : http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412291762177195?browse=search_50b4d8e4796de0090154336

Answer (score 0):

Put try and catch and check the exception you are getting.

Comment: Thanks you, but it was a FB bug : http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412291762177195